# How to get row, column indices of all non-NaN items in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan, indices

How do I iterate over a dataframe like the following and return the non-NaN value locations as a tuple. i.e.

```
df:

     0    1    2
0    NaN NaN   1
1    1   NaN  NaN
2    NaN  2   NaN
```

I would get an output of [(0, 1), (2, 0), (1, 2)].  Would the best way be to do a nested-for loop? Or is there an easier way I'm unaware of through Pandas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting (index, column) pairs for True elements of a boolean DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854091/getting-index-column-pairs-for-true-elements-of-a-boolean-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you don't need in order, you could stack the nonnull values and work on index values.

```
In [26]: list(df[df.notnull()].stack().index)
Out[26]: [(0L, '2'), (1L, '0'), (2L, '1')]

In [27]: df[df.notnull()].stack().index
Out[27]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2], [u'0', u'1', u'2']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1]])
```

Furthermore, using stack method, `NaN` are ignored anyway.

```
In [28]: list(df.stack().index)
Out[28]: [(0L, '2'), (1L, '0'), (2L, '1')]
```

Answer (score 5):

To get the non-null locations:

```
import numpy as np

>>> np.argwhere(df.notnull().values).tolist()
[[0, 2], [1, 0], [2, 1]]
```

If you really want them as tuple pairs, just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [tuple(pair) for pair in np.argwhere(df.notnull().values).tolist()]
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
```

To get the null locations:

```
>>> np.argwhere(df.isnull().values).tolist()
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: Could convert numpy array to tuple like `map(tuple, np.argwhere(df.notnull().values))`. However, one issue with this appraoch would arise if dataframe had non-indexed column names like `[a, b, c]` etc

Comment: I prefer a list comprehension over map.  This returns integer index locations, not column/index names (which would be easy to obtain btw).

Answer (score 1):

A direct way :

```
list(zip(*np.where(df.notnull())))
```

for

```
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 1)]
```