# Get all Row and Columns Positions of NaN values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, nan

How can I get all the Positions in Pandas where there are NAN values. For Example,

```
sample = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=[5,5]))
sample.iloc[0,0] = np.nan
sample.iloc[2,3] = np.nan
sample.iloc[4,3] = np.nan
```

is a Pandas Data Frame where the Positions such as (0,0), (2,3) and(4,3) have nan Values. Consequently, I want a list of Tuples like this

```
[(0,0),(2,3),(4,3)]
```

Ho can I get this ?

Regards

Comment: There are many existing duplicates, please use the search function.

Comment: or invert [How to get row, column indices of all non-NaN items in Pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375939/how-to-get-row-column-indices-of-all-non-nan-items-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3):

In this case since your column and index values are the row and column numbers you can first turn each entry to boolean using `isnull` and then filter for just the true values in the brackets with a lambda function and then turn the selected indices into a list.

```
sample.isnull().stack()[lambda x: x].index.tolist()
[(0, 0), (2, 3), (4, 3)]
```