# how to know row name and column name of a specific value in a dataframe by python?

Tags: python, dataframe

is it possible to know name of column and row for specific value of a dataframe?
for example i have a dataframe with name 'a' like this:

```
dataframe=pd.DataFrame([[0,5,2,1,3],[5,0,4,6,7],[2,4,0,8,9],[1,6,8,0,3],[3,7,9,3,0]] 
         , columns=["A","B","C","D","E"] , index=["A","B","C","D","E"])
```

and i want row name and column name of element '1' that is [A,D] and [D,A].

Answer (score 0):

@alireza - Below line will give you the row and column names and index. You can take user input, where I have put it as `== 1`. Code borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888137/get-row-and-column-index-of-value-in-pandas-df)

**Code**

```
[(i, np.where(dataframe[i] == 1)[0].tolist()) for i in list(dataframe) if len(np.where(dataframe[i] == 1)[0]) > 0]
```

**Output**

`[('A', [3]), ('D', [0])]`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by the condition you want, and then use this previous question:

[How to get row, column indices of all non-NaN items in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375939/how-to-get-row-column-indices-of-all-non-nan-items-in-pandas-dataframe)

To get indices of all non-`nan` values:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe=pd.DataFrame([[0,5,2,1,3],[5,0,4,6,7],[2,4,0,8,9],[1,6,8,0,3],[3,7,9,3,0]] , columns=["A","B","C","D","E"] , index=["A","B","C","D","E"])

df_ones = dataframe[dataframe == 1]
l = list(df_ones[df_ones.notnull()].stack().index)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def find_index_and_row(df):
    result = []
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        for column in df.columns:
            if row[column] == 1:
                result.append((index,column))
    return result
```